# ArgumentError Exception when doing Rails Tests with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minitest

Currently I'm having a test fail when I try to call `valid?` or `headshot_image` on my `Player` object.  I'm unsure where to go with it after looking at the trace.  Can anyone point out what I'm likely doing wrong? I can call any attribute on the player object and it reacts accordingly, but for `valid?` and `headshot_image` I get the error.

**Player.rb**

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :headshot_image, PlayerHeadshotUploader
end
```

**PlayerHeadshotUploader**

```
class PlayerHeadshotUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}"
  end


  def default_url
    "/uploads/player/no-profile-pic.jpg"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def filename
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename
  end

  protected

    def secure_token
      var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
      model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
    end

end
```

**Error and Trace**

```
(byebug) @player.headshot_image
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)

nil
(byebug) begin\; @player.headshot_image\; rescue Exception => e\; puts e.backtrace end
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:448:in `initialize'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:448:in `new'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:448:in `_mounter'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:142:in `headshot_image'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:366:in `headshot_image'
(byebug):1:in `block in <class:PlayerTest>'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:61:in `eval'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:61:in `safe_eval'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:55:in `warning_eval'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:31:in `block in multiple_thread_eval'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:94:in `allowing_other_threads'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:31:in `multiple_thread_eval'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/processors/command_processor.rb:163:in `block in run_cmd'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/processors/command_processor.rb:168:in `safely'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/processors/command_processor.rb:159:in `run_cmd'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/processors/command_processor.rb:133:in `repl'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/processors/command_processor.rb:97:in `process_commands'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/processors/command_processor.rb:55:in `at_line'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/context.rb:98:in `at_line'
/mnt/c/Users/mcdonaldd/Documents/Rails Projects/bane/test/models/player_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:PlayerTest>'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:98:in `block (3 levels) in run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:195:in `capture_exceptions'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:265:in `time_it'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:94:in `block in run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:360:in `on_signal'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:211:in `with_info_handler'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:93:in `run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:960:in `run_one_method'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:334:in `run_one_method'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:321:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `each'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `block in run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:360:in `on_signal'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:347:in `with_info_handler'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:319:in `run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/test_unit/line_filtering.rb:9:in `run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `block in __run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `map'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `__run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:136:in `run'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
nil
```

**Update adding player_test.rb by request**

```
require 'test_helper'

class PlayerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @player = players(:one)
  end

  test "first_name is present" do
    @player.first_name = nil
    assert_not @player.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please include relevant parts of `test/models/player_test.rb` as well

Comment: @Tachyons, thanks for taking time to look at my issue. I've added a test that gives me the issue and I can add anything else that I may have forgotten as well just let me know.

Comment: Any updates? I have exactly the same issue after Rails 5.2.1 migration.

Comment: @ThereAreFourLights, nope I had moved on in hopes of someone being able to answer - but so far nothing :(